# Sign Message Netherium

Tags: c#, asp.net, signature, nethereum

I'm trying to get a signature using the Netherium c# library, no errors occur, but the signature is incorrect

The code I use

```
string privateKey = "privateKey";
string dataToSign = @"Welcome
name";
string rpc = "https://1rpc.io/eth";

var web3 = new Web3(rpc);

var signer = new EthereumMessageSigner();
string signature = signer.EncodeUTF8AndSign(dataToSign, new EthECKey(privateKey));
Console.Writeline(signature);
```

when checking the signature it gives another wallet
https://etherscan.io/verifiedSignatures#

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out when you enter text in the format

```
string str = @"str1
str2";
```

She perceives it as str1\n\r and not str1\nstr2 as in js
Solve str.Replace("\r\n", "\n");